# How can I make my video fullscreen with mediaelement js?

Tags: angularjs, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I upgraded to version 4.2.8 from 2.23.4. It used to let me go fullscreen by double click now it won't.

angular directive code:

```
var videoHtml = '<video class="video-player mejs-ted" poster="' + videoThumb + '" 
  width="100%" height="' + heigth + '" preload="none"><source type="video/youtube" 
  src="' + videoLink + '" /></video>';

player.find('.js-tv-video').html(videoHtml);

angular.element('video').mediaelementplayer({
 success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
   $(".mejs-time-handle").append("<div class='mejs-time-handle-bar'></div>");
   $('.mejs-layers').remove();
 }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="js-tv-video"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you did not provide the JavaScript code for creating the MediaElementJsPlayer.

To add full screen feature, you have to add the 'fullscreen' to the features property when creating the player. See the API: https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/api.md#mediaelementplayer